# How to get std array size in a constant expression?

Tags: c++, clang, variable-length-array

Consider this code:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>

struct A {
    std::array<std::size_t, 4> test;
    void method() {
        std::size_t duptest[test.size()] = {}; // error: variable-sized object may not be initialized
    }
};
```

[Godbolt Clang](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:3,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:40,endLineNumber:7,positionColumn:40,positionLineNumber:7,selectionStartColumn:40,selectionStartLineNumber:7,startColumn:40,startLineNumber:7),source:%27%23include+%3Carray%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstddef%3E%0A%0Astruct+A+%7B%0A++++std::array%3Cstd::size_t,+4%3E+test%3B%0A++++void+method()+%7B%0A++++++++std::size_t+duptest%5Btest.size()%5D+%3D+%7B%7D%3B+//+error:+variable-sized+object+may+not+be+initialized%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%3B%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%233%27,t:%270%27)),k:51.00416360519226,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1400,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:3,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+14.0.0+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%233,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:48.99583639480775,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

It fails under Clang with the error in the comment. I don't understand why this is considered a VLA, because `test.size` is a `constexpr` function. How do I stop `duptest` from being interpreted as a VLA?

Comment: In C++ there is no such term - it's in C and it means Variably Modified type.

Comment: @JaMiT I'm asking why my code doesn't compile on clang

Comment: @JaMiT This shouldn't be any exntesnion in the first place as I see it.

Comment: @273K This should not be a VLA because the method `std::array::size` is `constexpr`.

Comment: [`constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) - *The `constexpr` specifier declares that it is possible to evaluate the value of the function or variable at compile time.* While [`consteval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval) - *The `consteval` specifier declares a function or function template to be an immediate function, that is, every potentially evaluated call (i.e. call out of an unevaluated context) to the function must (directly or indirectly) produce a compile time constant expression.*

Answer (score 3):

`test` means `this->test`, and evaluating `this.size()` must first evaluate `this->test`. But `this` is not a constant expression so `test.size()` is not a constant expression, even though `std::array::size` is `constexpr` and it doesn't use `test`. Therefore this is a VLA and is nonstandard.

You might use `std::tuple_size`.

```
size_t duptest[std::tuple_size<decltype(test)>()] = {};
```

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions ...and your code doesn't use a constant expression while my suggestion does. Thus mine works on all conformant compilers.

Comment: @HTNW Well I guess you are right but I can't drop my down-vote now - oh well. (I mean for the solution - I'm still certain the clangs fault and gcc right).

Comment: @AnArrayOfFunctions Both Clang and [GCC say](https://godbolt.org/z/7Wz14Kh6b) the same thing?? They both know your code has a VLA. GCC just has better support for VLAs (apparently GCC is okay with initializing them and Clang isn't, go figure) and GCC also doesn't tell you you're doing something out of standard without `-pedantic` (typical...).

Comment: @HTNW That's a flaw in the language then.

Comment: Is it really C++'s fault that GCC is a bit of a hot mess when it comes to compliance? I admit that `test.size()` *should* be designed to be a constant expression (maybe just making `size` `static` would work...) but VLAs *are outside C++* and everything weird about this question is really due to flaws in the implementations of VLAs (Clang is weirdly limited, GCC is weirdly secretive).

Comment: Just to clarify what (I think) @HTNW is trying to say: `constexpr` gives the compiler *permission* to do compile time evaluation, but doesn't *require* it--and in quite a few cases (including this one) even when it's marked `constexpr`, compile-time evaluation still isn't possible. If you want to guarantee compile-time evaluation, you use `consteval` instead (but `std::array::size()` isn't `consteval`, and even if it was, I'm not sure it would suffice for what's desired here).

Comment: `this` not being constexpr isn't a problem, as long as it's unused by the method. Consider `std::array<int, 4> test; constexpr auto size = test.size();`, which [does compile](https://godbolt.org/z/he6YaPcrE) at function scope.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat ? `this` being not constexpr is exactly the problem. Your example works because your `test.size()` doesn't involve `this` (as in `A`'s `this`). The OP's fails because it does involve that `this`.

Comment: @HTNW `.size()` is a non-static member function of `std::array`, so it does involve `this` pointing to that `std::array`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, but that `this` is irrelevant. The use of `A`'s `this` is the difference.

Comment: And why is that? That's what I'm asking, why is this difference there. May I suggest adding this to the answer?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Calling `test.size()` requires evaluating `test` (as an lvalue) so that `this` can be bound to it. In the progress of that evaluation, your example doesn't evaluate `A`'s `this` and is allowed, while the original does and so is banned. Since we just checked whether the receiver was a core constant expression, in `size` `this` is an allowed core constant expression too, though `size` probably doesn't use it. This doesn't belong in the answer since the original code fails before `std::array`'s `this` even actually exists.

Comment: What's "the receiver"? The address of `test` isn't a core constant, because `test` doesn't have static storage duration. And so is `A`'s `this` (also not a core constant). I'm starting to think that `this` has special treatment (stricter rules).

Comment: The lvalue `test` in your example *is* core constant, and so is its address (the rvalue `&test`), though that's not relevant. By "the receiver" I mean "the lvalue expression syntactically left of `.` whose value will become `*this` in the following method call." `test` is not a *constant expression* (nor is `&test`, still not quite relevant) because the result is not an allowed value for a constant expression. Core constant expressions are much wider than you'd think; that's why there's a difference between "core constant" and just "constant".

Answer (score 1):

The **problem** is that the expression `test.size()` is equivalent to `this->test.size()` but the `this` object is more of a run-time construct. In particular, in standard C++ the size of an array must be a compile-time constant(aka *constant expression*) which the expression `this->test.size()` is not. From [expr.const#2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.const#2):

> An expression `e` is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of `e`, following the rules of the abstract machine, would evaluate one of the following expressions:
>
> - `this`, except in a constexpr function or a constexpr constructor that is **being evaluated as part of `e`**;

Now in your example, `this` appears inside the member function `method` but the member function `method` is neither *constexpr* nor it is being evaluated as part of the expression `this->test.size()`.

Therefore `this->test.size()` cannot be used to specify the size of the array since that expression is not a compile-time constant.

Comment: This is not so simple. You can have non-constexpr arguments in a constexpr call, if the function doesn't use them. Both GCC and Clang accept `std::array<int, 4> test; constexpr auto size = test.size();`.

Comment: Nope, I meant to reply to both answers. If in my example the return value of `.size()` is constexpr despite the array not being constexpr, then I'm unsure why `this->test` not being constexpr ends up being problematic.

Comment: It compiles at function or namespace scope.

Comment: I can't promise I'll always do that, but point taken. *"it is obvious"* Maybe, but it contradicts your answer. `this` for a function-local variable is not constexpr, yet `.size()` called on such a variable ends up being constexpr.

Comment: Yep, I do mean free functions. Am I not seeing something obvious? I'm talking about `this` pointing to the instance of `std::array` inside of its `.size()` method.

Comment: `.size()` is a member function of `std::array`, so it has `this` inside, which isn't `constexpr` in this case, which doesn't stop the return value form being constexpr.

Comment: Yeah, and similarly in `this->test.size()` neither `this` nor the address pf `&test` are needed to compute `.size()`, for the exact reason you stated. I'm unsure why it's so hard to get my point accross.

Comment: It's obvious that there's no `this` in free funtions, but that's not what I'm talking about. I have a feeling that you're not actually reading my comments. :( Let's just drop this matter.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I've added an explanation using the standard which explains the observed behavior. You can also use it to find out how in your example of free function the program works. In particular, because in case of free function, if the `this` pointer is used then it is inside a *constexpr* member function `size` and also being evaluated as part of the expression. So it(should, which it does) works in your case.