# Why are member functions returning non-static data members not core constant expressions?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constant-expression

Consider the following example: ([Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/o91YE5Mxr))

```
struct S {
    static bool const x = true;
    const bool y = true;
    constexpr bool f() const { return x; }
    constexpr bool g() const { return y; }
};

int main() {

    const S s{};
    static_assert(s.f()); // OK
    static_assert(s.g()); // error
}
```

g++trunk gives the following errors:

```
error: non-constant condition for static assertion static_assert(s.g());
                                                                  
error: the value of 's' is not usable in a constant expression

note: 's' was not declared 'constexpr'
```

Why `s.f()` is core constant expression while `s.g()` is not?

Where C++ standard mandates this behavior?

Comment: What if I add a constructor to `S` that sets the value of `y`? What if that constructor is just forward declared as `S(bool);` and its definition isn't visible to a translation unit calling `s.g()`?

Comment: For same reason your old deleted post didn't work. [Why a static data member of a non-constexpr object is a core constant expressions but a non-static member is not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73690772/why-a-static-data-member-of-a-non-constexpr-object-is-a-core-constant-expression)

Comment: @John In what sense does it *not* answer your question? The question is effectively the same, the fact that you are wrapping the access in a member function is a distraction and does not change the answer.

Comment: @KonradRudolph "Where C++ standard mandates this behavior?"

Comment: @KonradRudolph - the member function `f` does not evaluate `this` but `g` does. Do you see the answer there is applicable here?

Comment: @Caleth I already gave the standard reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72023209/how-to-get-std-array-size-in-a-constant-expression/72023705#72023705) in my answer which is the same as your answer below. [Dupe1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72597798/why-are-only-some-consts-useable-in-compile-time-array-sizes) and [Dupe2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72023209/how-to-get-std-array-size-in-a-constant-expression/72023705#72023705)

Comment: @John Yes, it’s directly applicable, for the precise reason your comment mentions: “the member function `f` does not evaluate `this`, but `g` does”.

Comment: @John Both the current and the previously linked duplicate contain references to the relevant standard wording. It also just follows straightforward (though admittedly not obviously!) from the semantics of static and non-static members: for static members, there is no `this`. For non-static members, there is. And if `this` isn’t `constexpr`, then neither is any part of it (i.e. any member), except if explicitly marked as such. This really does *not* require an explicit reference to standard wording.

Comment: @JasonLiam I'm not doing that. Anyway, I see your answer doesn't satisfy me. Basically, because the member function `S::g` is constexpr. Indeed the wording of the standard you provide is apply here and there but the explanation is not good as far as I can tell.

Comment: @John The important thing is that `y` is a non-static data member while `x` is a `constexpr static`. That is, `return y;` is the same as `return this->y;` while there is no use of `this` in `return x;`.

Comment: There is a basic difference in constness. x is a complete const object and can even be put in ROM. y, OTOH, is a const but not a complete const object. It can be replaced with a different value as of c++20 so is not a core const.

Comment: "`S::g` is constexpr" Okay, but in your code `s` is not `constexpr` so that's neither here nor there. Indeed if I just change the declaration from `const S s{};` to `constexpr S s{};`, [it works fine](https://godbolt.org/z/TGjqvcP1x)

Comment: @NathanPierson - "_Okay, but in your code s is not constexpr_" But this requirement is not explicitly specified in the bullet (2.1).

Comment: @NathanPierson - I mean, I understood the bullet as: `e` (`s.g()`) is core constant expression if `e` evaluates `this` and `this` is evaluated in constexpr function, and that constexpr function is part of the expression `e`. So if I understood correctly, there is no requirement for the subexpression `s` to be constexpr.

Comment: @Konrad: The quotation in this question is NOT the relevant standard verbiage.  My answer to [the follow-on question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73694162/103167) dives into the requirements that are relevant.