# How to make `this` pointer constant expression?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, this, constant-expression

This is a follow-up question is my previous question: [Why are member functions returning non-static data members not core constant expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73691233/19495502)

The reduced version of the example mentioned in that question is:

```
struct S {
    const bool x = true;
    constexpr bool f() { return x; }
};

int main() {
  S s{};
  static_assert(s.f()); // error: 's' is not a constexpr;
}
```

The applicable wording from the standard is N4861: [[expr.const]/(5.1)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const#5.1):

> An expression `E` is a core constant expression unless the evaluation
> of `E`, following the rules of the abstract machine
> ([intro.execution]), would evaluate one of the following:
>
> - (5.1) `this` ([expr.prim.this]), except in a `constexpr` function ([dcl.constexpr]) that is being evaluated as part of `E`;

As far as I can parse, the expression `E` is `s.f()` and it evaluates `this` since `s.f()` returns a non-static member `this->x`. But that falls under the "except" part: the member function `s.S::f()` is constexpr function that's being evaluated as part of `s.f()`. If I parsed correctly, I'm expecting `s.f()` to be constant expression and the assertion success.

However, this bullet doesn't specify a requirement that says that `s` has to be a constant expression. I can't understand why declaring `s` as `constexpr` compiles the program even though there's no requirement, defined in this bullet, for `s` to be `constexpr`.

I'm just applying the wording `(5.1)` in my example but I can't see that `constexpr` is required here unless I'm missing any other rule.

Comment: You are referring to the C++17 draft, are you interested in a C++17 perspective specifically?

Comment: By the way, there's more bullets there. The genuine offender is later in the list.

Comment: are you asking specific about wording? because it's reasonable any parameter (including this) need to be constexpr to evaluate constexpr result.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica - Are the wording meaningfully different?

Comment: Potentially. Genuine cleanup and wording issues being resolved. Not to mention enhancements to constant evaluation as part of the language evolving.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica - I updated the question with the N4861 draft.

Comment: `s` is not a constexpr.  Just as indicated by the compiler error.

Comment: I would say that issue is not in 5.1, You would have same issue with free function `constexpr bool f(S& s) { return s.x; }` [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/G3h74e88j)

Comment: If you review basic.life, you will find that const members of an object that is not const, may be transparently replaced with different values. Hence `x` can't be a core const. And running it through a constexpr function doesn't make it so. That's why `s.x` is not a core const.

Comment: @doug: That wasn't so in C++17, which are the rules OP is using.

Comment: @BenVoigt True for c++17 but the Op had edited his post for c++20.

Comment: @Eljay - _"s is not a `constexpr`. "_ That's not a requirement for (5.1) to be applied though.

Comment: @Jarod42 - _" You would have same issue with free function"_ In case of free functions, the arguments shall be constant expressions in order for the call to appear in a constant expression context.

Comment: @John: `f3` on my demo shows that non-constexpr argument is allowed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `return x;` performs lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, the whole kaboodle is not a core constant expression:

> An expression E is a core constant expression unless the evaluation of E, following the rules of the abstract machine ([intro.execution]), would evaluate one of the following:
>
> - [an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion unless it is applied to](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const#5.8)
>
>   - a non-volatile glvalue that refers to an object that is usable in constant expressions, or
>   - a non-volatile glvalue of literal type that refers to a non-volatile object whose lifetime began within the evaluation of E;

lvalue-to-rvalue conversion *is* applied to `this->S::x`, which is generally forbidden, and neither of the exceptions apply to permit it.

The more relevant exception applies if `x` (which resolves to `this->S::x`) is an object that is usable in constant expressions.  But it only would be if the `struct S` object were usable in constant expressions:

> - [a non-mutable subobject or reference member of any of the above.](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const#4.8)

That requires it to be potentially-constant:

> - [A variable is potentially-constant if it is `constexpr` or it has reference or `const`-qualified integral or enumeration type.](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const#3)
> - [A constant-initialized potentially-constant variable is usable in constant expressions at a point P if](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const#4) ...

And `S s{};` is not potentially-constant.  So it is not usable in constant expressions, and neither are its subobjects.

---

To answer the title question, `this` is not a core constant expression, because it is the address of an object with automatic storage duration; that address may change at runtime.  This is completely irrelevant for the `static_assert` in the question code: Being a constant pointer value is neither necessary nor sufficient for a `this` pointer to be "usable in constant expressions", which in turn is not sufficient for the object found through the pointer to be usable in constant expressions.

Comment: Yep, pretty much requires `s` to be declared `constexpr S s{};` to the code to work.

Comment: @John • Change `S s{};` (a runtime object, not constexpr) to `S s{false};`.  Since that is a *run time* object, I don't see how the compiler could make *compile time* constant expression sense out of it.

Comment: @Eljay - Changing `S s{};` to `S s{false};` does nothing at least as far as I can tell.

Comment: @John • The `s` object is a **runtime** object.  You can't use it as a **compile time** `constexpr` object.  At **compile time**, the compiler has no insight into the state of the object.  (If you aren't getting this, which is what Ben said in his answer, why did you accept the answer?)

Comment: @Eljay - _"You can't use it as a compile time constexpr object."_ Consider the function `f` returns `const bool&`, then you can do this: `constexpr const bool &r = s.f();` even though `s` is not declared as `constexpr`

Comment: @Eljay _" why did you accept the answer?"_ I can't understand what you're trying to say. Can you clarify? Do you really know what my question is talking about?

Comment: @John • *then you can do this: `constexpr const bool &r = s.f();`* Doesn't compile on my machine.  I thought your question was about "How to make `this` pointer constant expression?"   You can do that by doing:  `constexpr S s{};`

Comment: @Eljay My question is why `s.f()` in `static_assert(s.f())` is not core constant expression. And the answer is pretty straightforward: because `s.f()` involves lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. Now, what's your problem?

Comment: @John • *Now, what's your problem?*  `constexpr const bool &r = s.f();` does not compile. *But declaring `s` as `constexpr` is not a requirement for `this` to be context expression.* That is incorrect, it **is** a requirement.

Comment: @Eljay No, it [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/aEsdGM66E). Note, `s` in the demo is **not** `constexpr`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248017/discussion-between-eljay-and-john).

Comment: @Eljay: It is not necessary for `s` to be usable in a constant expression for a pointer to it (such as `this` within its member function) to be a core constant expression.  e.g. any global object has an address fixed at link time, so a pointer to such an object is core constant.  But the pointer `&s` being constant is completely irrelevant to the `static_assert` here, it is neither necessary nor sufficient.