# Why this expression is not constant expression

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constant-expression

I have the following code:

```
struct S {
    const bool x = true;
    constexpr const bool& f() { return x; }
} s{};

int main() {
  static_assert(s.f()); // error: s is not declared as 'constexpr';
}
```

Note that, this is a dupe for the question [How to make `this` pointer constant expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73694162/19495502) because the the expression `E = s.f()` does not evaluates lvalue-to-rvalue conversion ([[expr.const]/(5.8)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const#5.8)).

Also, this question is not a dupe for the question [How to get std array size in a constant expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72023209/how-to-get-std-array-size-in-a-constant-expression) because the expression `E = s.f()` does evaluates `this` in a constexpr function `S::f` that's evaluated as part of the expression `s.f()` ([[expr.const]/(5.1)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/expr.const#5.1)).

Now my question is, which bullet in `[expr.const]/5` (*if any*) is applied to the above example?

Comment: _does not evaluates lvalue-to-rvalue conversion_ ??? `static_assert` is interested in the value of the expression. How do you get one without L2R conversion?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Are you looking at the questions mentioned above?

Comment: @lorro What will be changed if you do so? Really nothing.

Comment: In `static_assert`, L2R conversion is performed on `s.f()`. `s.f()` denotes `s.x`. What is the difference between performing L2R conversion on `x` in `return x` and here? The expressions denote the same object.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer - I disagree. Binding a reference of type `const bool&` to an lvalue of type `const bool` doesn't involve lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.

Comment: But the `static_assert` itself does involve it. It asserts on the *value* of `s.f()`. That makes `s.f()` not a constant expression.

Comment: Because `s` is not `constexpr`, that makes `this` not `constexpr`, that means `s.f()` is not a `constexpr` function in that context.